# how to extract the digit part from the string

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column that has a string in it as follow

```
Data
black83736
white87
white893
pink82928
pink1
black27
...
...
```

I want to just get the digits out of that column.

**Edit**

I would prefer mysql solution

Comment: This question *is* a duplicate. The first one who finds it, wins ;)

Comment: what about what about wh1te87, is this another possible scenario?

Comment: wh1te87 is not possible scenario

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this mysql Solution :
(updated)

```
SELECT replace(reverse(FORMAT(reverse(COLUMN_NAME), 0)), ',', '') as number from TABLE_NAME;
```

this is for your particular case, where you want the numbers in the end.

so first we

`Reverse`, so numbers come to beginning

`format`, so alphabets are removed, format is used for formatting a number with specified decimal places, here we specify it to 0.

`reverse` again -> to obtain the original number

`replace` ',' to '' -> to remove the effect of formatting of second step.

**

### (UPDATE)

**
the above solution doesnt work for numbers ending in 0's (thanks to karolis for telling)

so for that

```
SELECT replace(replace(reverse(FORMAT(reverse(concat(numbers, '9099')), 0)), ',', ''), '9099', '') as number from test1;
```

Here we are appending '9099' to the end of the number, and then removing 9099 in the end.

9099 ? just a number which would be highly in-probable to occur in your columns

Comment: it just gave me blank number fields

Comment: @Autolycus, i will try it out and update you in 10 mins, must be some minor error.

Comment: @stereofrog i remember trying something similar in my lab class, in oracle DB, so i am trying out right now and will update :)

Comment: @Pheonix What about `abc5000 `?

Comment: @Karolis yes it will work for all string with numbers in the end. tested it out with a list of 10 such random strings.

Comment: @Pheonix No you you haven't tested :)

Comment: (edit) @Karolis no it doesnt works, 000 are removed, let me find a solution :-/

Comment: @Karolis : updated solution for that 00's problem... this solution still has less then 10 function calls :P so i suppose is better then 10 replace calls ;)

Comment: @Pheonix I don't know... it's a hack :) But ok, +1, because you did so much investigation.

Comment: I was opting for `CAST` instead of `FORMAT`, it gives a warning however.

Answer (score 3):

```
$result = preg_replace('~[^0-9]*~', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's very inelegant, but currently the only reliable **MySQL only** solution that I know:

```
select replace(column_name,
    replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
    replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
    column_name, 
    0, ''), 1, ''), 2, ''), 3, ''), 4, ''), 
    5, ''), 6, ''), 7, ''), 8, ''), 9, ''), '')
```

Comment: Can anybody explain, why did I get the downvote? Does anybody know a better method which actually works?

Comment: There is, in fact, too much replaces, it's in the area of 2.

Comment: @Karolis: unclear, unradable((((((((((((((((((())))))))))))))))

Comment: @Karolis You will find the answer [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600974/how-to-extract-the-digit-part-from-the-string)

Comment: @PMV Yes, but do you know a better MySQL only solution?

Comment: @ViswanathanIyer You posted me a link to the same page. Do you know a better MySQL only solution?

Comment: @genesisφ The same question for you :)

Comment: @Karolis I didn't downvote, I was just answering your question on why you got downvoted.  Also, I like your answer better than the accepted one, but I'd still be annoyed if I found it in the wild.

Comment: @Lode Your revision changed the main logic that was needed to solve this problem. So I have rollbacked to an earlier revision.

Comment: Thanks @Karolis, I mistakenly thought the code was meant to remove the digits and leave the letters.

Answer (score 0):

```
filter_var('stri99ng', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

> I would prefer mysql solution

Well, you shouldn't unless you have powerful processor or this query does not return many results. MySQL isn't generally good for any string manipulation operations.